# OpenEdge Trouble fetching data from a SOAP API

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm using the built-in .NET classes to fetch data from a SOAP API. The following lines return the response message.

`responseReader = NEW StreamReader (response:GetResponseStream(), encoding:default).` 
`content =  responseReader:ReadToEnd(). /*LONGCHAR*/`
`response:Close().`

This works fine if there is only the SOAP XML message in the response. But in my case there is a possibility that the response contains additional files with formats like PDF, PNG and so on that are not encoded as Base64. This leads to an error as soon as the data is stored in the LONGCHAR variable.

I tried a few things. One was to change the encoding for the StreamReader object. This didn't cause an error, but it did corrupt the contents of the file, making it impossible to open. I'm not sure whether it's the correct way to handle use a LONGCHAR variable in this case, but I have not been able to find a way to get the data out of the StreamReader as a MEMPTR.

Comment: SOAP is always XML, which can contain base64 encoded blobs. If you are getting unencoded blobs, then you are not using a SOAP web service. Please enlighten me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Is there a (good) reason for using the .NET classes instead of Progress native SOAP client? I've used the latter with some success. Using the documentation tool (bproxsdto4gl) also gives some handy code templates.

Comment: @Jensd I couldn't find a way to add SSL client authentication with the native SOAP client, which I need in this case. This is only possible with Progress version 12.4 or higher according to [this](https://community.progress.com/s/article/Progress-support-client-side-digital-certificates-with-SSL) article. Our customer is using Progress 12.2.

Comment: @Stefan Drissen The response is a Multipart Message.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-8.0), this class

> Implements a TextReader that reads characters from a byte stream in a particular encoding.

So if you're getting (say) PDF data that contains null bytes then you are going to have problems. You may want to look at a different Stream type in this case.

Or you could use the OpenEdge HTTP Client, which can deal with MTOM responses quite nicely, although you have to construct the request yourself. See https://community.progress.com/s/article/P148513 or https://community.progress.com/s/article/How-to-work-with-MultiPart-Messages-using-HttpClient .

(https://community.progress.com/s/article/Is-there-an-HTTP-client-for-OpenEdge has a nice list of links too)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. According to [this](https://community.progress.com/s/article/Progress-support-client-side-digital-certificates-with-SSL) the Progress HTTP Client only supports client side auth with Progress Versions => 12.4. Our customer uses 12.2 and we use the x509 class for Certificate in this case.

Do you know any other Stream Class that that could be helpful?